# Make list the width of an input tag without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the following snippet of HTML:

```
<input><ul>
```

We have an input tag, followed by a list.  (The list will have actual items, but to keep things compact I left them out here.)  Now, it is possible to control the width of the list using CSS, and likewise for the input tag.

I want to leave the input tag at its default width, and then make list width have a matching width.  I could of course use JavaScript's getComputedStyle.  In theory, this would cause problems if the user disables JavaScript, but in practice, I'm actually coding a (very minimalistic) autocomplete widget (like on Wikipedia, but less fancy), so it won't work without JavaScript anyway.

But still: is this possible?  I know basically nothing about CSS, so forgive me if this is supposed to be obvious.

Comment: Interesting question.  You can use inline block styling (adding a wrapper that's inline block around both the list and the input), but if the list item text is too long, it'll extend the width.  What do you want it to do in that scenario? https://jsfiddle.net/s8dujmto/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'd do this with a wrapper element set to `display:table` or `display:table-cell` (it doesn't matter which, an anonymous object will be created for the other one) along with a very small specified width. The used width of the wrapper will be forced to be at least as the wide as the input box and then the list will fit inside that.

(The demo CSS and HTML markup borrowed from Joseph Marikle's answer)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width:1px;
}

/* for demo only */
ul{list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0;background:#ae0}.wrapper{margin-bottom:1em;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input>
  <ul>
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li>test 2</li>
    <li>test 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input>
  <ul>
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li>test 2 tetts 3 stsdgsdf stsdgsdf</li>
    <li>test 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for.  Except that the text wraps if it's too long, whereas I wanted each entry to be one line long, always.  But there's probably any easy way to fix that.

Comment: Try `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the wrapping

Answer (score 1):

If you're not too averse to using newer CSS standards, I'd suggest using flexbox.  It adapts both ways making sure both elements are the same width without having to set or calculate explicit values.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* for demo only */
ul{list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0;background:#ae0}.wrapper{margin-bottom:1em;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input>
  <ul>
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li>test 2</li>
    <li>test 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input>
  <ul>
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li>test 2 tetts 3 stsdgsdf stsdgsdf</li>
    <li>test 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a VERY interesting effect you've created.  I've never seen an autocomplete widget that works this way, but I now wonder if maybe your way is better and everyone else is doing it "wrong".  Your way has the default width be the width of the input tag, but if the list has some wide items, then it stretches, and the input tag stretches with them.  However, I worry that this might be a bit disorienting.  Input tags don't normally stretch and shrink like that.  Never the less, if no one comes up with an answer closer to what I asked, I will accept this one.  It's really cool.

Comment: @MarkVY I wouldn't say everyone is doing it wrong per se.  It's more like flexbox is the bleeding edge of what's acceptable in production code now.  It was only recently that major frameworks like twitter bootstrap and Semantic UI (I think?) have been relying on it.  For really good backwards compatibility, you would need to use javascript.  There's just no other way that I know of to do that reliably without flexbox or javascript.

Comment: No, I don't mean about flexbox.  I mean the effect where the input tag stretches to accommodate the widest list item.  I've never seen an autocomplete widget that does that.  (See, for instance, Wikipedia or Google: they both are fixed with, even if the suggestion doesn't fit.)

Answer (score -1):

try

`<ul style = "width: 40px">` //change 40px to a matching width

Comment: But I don't know what width the input tag will have.  Different browsers may have different defaults, perhaps drastically different even.

Comment: Try to set the input width the same as the ul width. It would be easier to fix it with a demo, try to use jsfiddle or codepen ;)

Comment: But then what if I find that Browser A has a default width of 144px, and Browser B has a default width of 72px, and Browser C has a default width of 288px?  There are many strange browsers out there: lynx, mobile browsers, etc.  Not to mention that there are users who change the browsers default settings, use custom stylesheets, and so on.